# javascript function to avoid two decimal points (ex: 12.1.1 ) in html input text field

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me out to found a solution to validate a text field to accept a valid decimal number. I tried something like

```
function fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(txt) {
    if (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58 || event.keyCode == 46) {
        var txtbx = document.getElementById(txt);
        var amount = document.getElementById(txt).value;
        var present = 0;
        var count = 0;

        if (amount.indexOf(".", present) || amount.indexOf(".", present + 1)); {
            // alert('0');
        }

        /*if(amount.length==2)
              {
                if(event.keyCode != 46)
                return false;
              }*/
        do {
            present = amount.indexOf(".", present);
            if (present != -1) {
                count++;
                present++;
            }
        }
        while (present != -1);
        if (present == -1 && amount.length == 0 && event.keyCode == 46) {
            event.keyCode = 0;
            //alert("Wrong position of decimal point not  allowed !!");
            return false;
        }

        if (count >= 1 && event.keyCode == 46) {
            event.keyCode = 0;
            //alert("Only one decimal point is allowed !!");
            return false;
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            var lastdigits = amount.substring(amount.indexOf(".") + 1, amount.length);
            if (lastdigits.length >= 4) {
                //alert("Two decimal places only allowed");
                event.keyCode = 0;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        event.keyCode = 0;
        //alert("Only Numbers with dot allowed !!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: @Farkie then retag, don't downvote.

Comment: I never downvoted - I edited and retagged.

Comment: If you just want to test, if the input is a number, you can use isNaN() or you can parse the input to a float number with parseFloat() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 1):

If you only want decimal numbers, then a simple regex suffices:

```
function validateNumber(num) {
  return /^-?[1-9][0-9]*(.[0-9]+)?$/.test(num);
}
```

In English, this means

- `^`: Start at the beginning of the input.
- `-?`: Optional negative sign.
- `[1-9]`: The first character must be a digit in the range `1-9` (i.e. no leading zeros).
- `[0-9]*` That must be followed by zero or more digits in the range `0-9`.
- `(.[0-9]+)?`: That can optionally be followed by a decimal point and one or more digits in the range `0-9`.
- `$`: One you get here, it must be the end of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it simple:

```
var txtbx = document.getElementById("txt");

txtbx.addEventListener("keyup",function(e) {
  var parsed = parseFloat(txtbx.value)||0;
  if(parsed!=txtbx.value) txtbx.value = parsed;
});
```

Comment: thanks Jan Turoň.. got solution